# Count number of rasterized fragments

Tags: c++, opengl

**Abtract problem:** I need to count the fragments a given geometry generated while it was rendered/rasterized regardless if those fragments passed the depth/stencil test or not.

**Context:** I'm currently trying to implement lens flares for a project I'm working on. I'm using OpenGL occlusion querying to count the pixels which are visible from a light source by rendering a screen aligned quad at the position of the light source while having a query active to determine the number of visible fragments of the light source. This quad has a given `width` and `height` so it should initially have `width * height` pixels at *some* distance from the camera. After that I want to adjust the alpha value of the actual flare effect to account for the occluded parts of the light source. To do this I need to know the total amount of fragments that assembled the originally rendered quad.

So, does anyone know how I can determine the number of fragments that are generated from a given rendering operation?

Comment: This isn't making to much sense to me. You say that your already using an occlusion query to count pixels but then ask how to determine how to find out how many pixels where rendered?

Comment: I'm trying to get the number of pixels that were tested by the occlusion query including those which did not pass the depth/stencil test but it seems that that isn't possible to do with only one pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were already suggested occlusion query, which is exactly the right tool for this job. Your struggle lies withing the misconception that you try doing everything in only one pass.

Split your problem into multiple sub-tasks. In your case you should add one render pass just for the occlusion query of the geometry (without shaders, textures, etc) with all the fragment discarding tests being disabled.

Note that occlusion query counts all fragments that just pass all tests, but also counts them if depth and color writes are disables. So you can draw your occlusion query quad without it becoming visible or corrupt the depth buffer.